# Php file opens instead of the bootstrap modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

HERE IS THE WEBSITE: sacbikerepair.com
(go to services, then click on 'get it' under flat tire service)

I am trying to set up a website where a user can click on a type of service. After they click it, they will get a modal which will prompt them for their personal information(like name, phone-number etc.).

But there is a problem. When I click on 'get it'(which prompts the modal), I am taken to my php file. I want my php file to run only after the modal is shown and the user clicks on 'submit'.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form action="php/flat_service_process.php" method="POST">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white p-0 pt-1">
            <h2 class="lato-font">Flat Tire
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title display-4 mb-0">20$</h3>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-larger-text">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Inner-Tube
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Inner-Tube Removal and Reinstallation
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <hr class="gradient-on-ends m-0 p-0">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title display-4 mb-0">35$</h3>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-larger-text">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Inner-Tube & Tire
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Inner-Tube & Tire Removal and Reinstallation
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flatTireModal">
              Get It
            </button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

The php file is empty.

Feel free to ask questions if I was unclear.

Comment: Maybe use JS and an IFrame to load the php file inline after the button is clicked?

Comment: When you add a button inside a form tag, and the button type isn't defined, then the default type of the button will become submit, as it is the default interpretation of the button. Try placing the button outside of the form tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `button` is being treated as a submit button.

Add the `type="button"` to "Get It" button. See below,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flatTireModal" >Get It</button>
```

The reason for this is due to the default interpretation of a non-defined type button inside a form tag. Buttons will always have type `submit` as their default type. Thanks @Martin for the heads up to add why it is happenning.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

It is worth doing the same for other two buttons as well to avoid this sort of problems.

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Correct answer, but you might wanna include information as to why the problem occurs, to teach OP. The reason to why the problem occurs, is due to the default interpretation of a non-defined type button inside a form tag. Those buttons will always have *submit* as their default type.

Comment: @Martin : I have added the reason. Thank you very much for the heads up. Cheers.